# Using SqlDataAdapter.Update() with Parameters

Tags: .net, parameters, transactions, sqldataadapter

How trying to figure out how to use SqlDataAdapter.Update(DataTable) method using a parameterised query. How can I add the values to the command without iterating over the whole DataTable?

And how can I execute the SqlDataAdapter insert and update methods within a transaction?

What I have so far is the following:

```
internal void InsertUpdate(DataTable dt){
    using(var con = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString)){
         var sb = new StringBuilder();
         sb.AppendLine("UPDATE myTable");
         sb.AppendLine("SET prop1 = @p1, prop2 = qp2");
         sb.AppendLine("WHERE id = @id");
         var cmd = new SqlCommand(sb.ToString());
         cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("p1", ????);
         cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("p2", ????);
         cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("id", ????);
         var adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(selectQuery, con);
         adapter.UpdateCommand = cmd;
         adapter.Update(dt);
    }
}
```

Best Regards

Jay

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using Parameters.AddWithValue(...), use Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter(...)) and use one of the last three constructors for SqlParameter documents here: [SqlParameter Class MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparameter.aspx). They allow you to specify a column which will be used at runtime to fill the parameter. For example, here is a line from one of my current programs:

```
UpdateCommand.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("FK_CustomerID", global::System.Data.OleDb.OleDbType.Integer, 0, global::System.Data.ParameterDirection.Input, ((byte)(0)), ((byte)(0)), "FK_CustomerID", global::System.Data.DataRowVersion.Current, false, null));
```

Note the second use of "FK_CustomerID", which indicates to use this DataTable column for the parameter.

Regarding using transactions, take a look at this for some ideas: [Transactions with TableAdapters, a lazy man's approach](http://weblogs.asp.net/ryanw/archive/2006/03/30/441529.aspx).
Regards, Drew